# How should I design my table(s) to represent a list of objects, some of which are components of other objects?

Tags: database-design

My initial concept of this manufacturing DB would have a table where all parts and materials used to make finished products are part of a table:

```
Raw Material A
Raw Material B...Z
Widget A
Widget B...Z
```

Widgets are components of Finished Products. Raw Materials can be used to make Widgets but can also just be a component of a Finished Product.

I need to keep track of inventory for everything in this table, which means I need to be able to represent what Raw Materials are consumed when making a Widget.

#### Considerations

What direction should I go with this? My first thought would be a nullable column like `component_id_needed` and `component_qt` and multiple table rows for the same Widget if multiple Raw Materials were needed.